# How to convert a flat list to a binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

Let's say I have a list like so:

```
flat_list = [None, 10, 5, 15, None, None, 11, 22]
```

I know the algorithm for creating a tree from a nestled list goes like:

```
def create_tree_from_nested_list(node_list):
    if not node_list:
        return node_list
    d, l, r = node_list
    tree = BinaryTree(d)
    tree.set_left(create_tree_from_nested_list(l))
    tree.set_right(create_tree_from_nested_list(r))
    return tree
```

The output for the code above would be:

```
10
(l)    5
(r)    15
(l)        11
(r)        22
```

How would I go about creating a function to flat lists into trees so that the left ones are stored at index position `2*i` and the right ones are stored at index position `2 * i + 1` and the output is the same as the output for the nested list. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the love of Guido! Stop with the getters and setters. This ain't Java.

Comment: In any event, I don't really get your question. What is the expected output? What would be the equivalent nested list?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have clarified better. The output should be the same for the nested list and the flat list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your nested list code to work on a flat list. Since there's not an easy way to split out the sub-tree lists, I suggest instead passing the index of the node you want to build as an argument, along with the whole flat list. The index will have a default of `1` (so you don't need to pass it for the root node):

```
def create_tree_from_flat_list(node_list, index=1):
    if index >= len(node_list) or node_list[index] is None:
        return None
    d = node_list[index]
    l = index * 2
    r = l + 1
    tree = BinaryTree(d)
    tree.set_left(create_tree_from_flat_list(node_list, l))
    tree.set_right(create_tree_from_flat_list(node_list, r))
    return tree
```

It's not at all essential to have separate `d`, `l` and `r` variables in this function (they could each be computed right where they're used). I did it this way to make the function more obviously parallel to the nested list version. `l` and `r` are the indexes of the roots of the left and right subtrees.

Example output:

```
> print(create_tree_from_flat_list([None, 10, 5, 15, None, None, 11, 22]))
10
(l)    5
(r)    15
(l)        11
(r)        22
```